# Just displaying the SSRS report image

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have an ssrs report server that I can display reports.  When I view the page i get the familiar control to set properties etc.  That generates an image with a url that hits this page: "Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" - with some scary looking ids and stuff.

Is there a way to get this image with all the controls around it?  My goal is to embed this image in an email and on a webpage.

Thanks!

PS: I'm a complete SSRS newbie so sorry if this is totally obvious...